# How to test React APP in development on an actual phone?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, testing, mobile

I am writing a React APP for desktop, Android, and IOS.

I am currently testing it on my desktop fine. But how do I get it onto my phone to test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tunnels. One example is `ngrok` if you are on `localhost:3000` you can simply do:

```
ngrok http 3000
```

It will give you a link that you can visit on your phone. It will also update every time you update your react app.

installation: https://ngrok.com/download

docs: https://ngrok.com/docs